# Can't override Date toString in node.js

Tags: node.js, date, overriding, tostring

In node.js:

```
Date.prototype.toString = function dateToString() {
 return `${this.getMonth()}/${this.getDate()} of ${this.getFullYear()}`
};
console.log("====>", new Date(2019, 0, 1))
```

I would expect "2/11 of 2019", instead I get "2019-01-01T02:00:00.000Z".

Is node.js broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think that logging a `Date` calls the `Date` object's `toString` function, so you could just override it - but that's not necessarily true.  Some implementations will give you output similar to `toISOString` instead of `toString`.  Nowhere in the ECMAScript spec does it define how `console.log` should behave.  Even in [the WhatWG Console Standard](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/), it doesn't describe how to log `Date` objects - so you're in implementation dependent territory.

So, instead of overriding a function on the `Date` prototype, you'd have to [override the `console.log` function](http://tobyho.com/2012/07/27/taking-over-console-log/), check if an argument passed to it is a `Date`, and if so convert it to a string instead, and then pass it along to the original `console.log` function.  I'll leave that up to you (or someone else) to implement.

Or just remember to call `.toString()`, as ChuongTran showed in their answer.

Comment: Thanks Matt, with Java background I wrongly expected that that Console.log would mimic System.println...

Answer (score 0):

I think node.js not broken. But you need to call toString() to get a string in console.log

```
 Date.prototype.toString = function dateToString() {
  return `${this.getMonth()}/${this.getDate()} of ${this.getFullYear()}`
 };
 var date = new Date(2019, 0, 1);
 console.log("====>", date.toString());
 console.log("====>", date.toDateString());
```

Output:

====> 0/1 of 2019

====> Tue Jan 01 2019